# Flask middleware on abort 401 causing a 500

Tags: python, flask, middleware, abort

I have a middleware in my Flask app that is used to authenticate a JSON Web Token coming in the header of the request and is checking to verify it, below is my middleware class:

```
class AuthMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        path = environ.get('PATH_INFO')
        if path != '/authenticate' or path != '/token':
            token = environ.get('HTTP_X_ACCESS_TOKEN')
            verfied_token = verify_token(token)
            if verfied_token is False:
                abort(401)
            elif verfied_token is True:
                # payload = get_token_payload(token)
                # check_permissions(payload)
                pass

        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

`verify_token()` is a function that will return True or False, and if it returns False, I want it to abort with an error 401. However, it aborts with an error 500:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2015 11:37:25] "POST /role HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 180, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
File "/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 168, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File "/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/middleware.py", line 24, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_response) 
File "/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 605, in __call__
raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs)
BadRequest: 400: Bad Request
```

In my views, I abort a 401 like it should, but here it seems to be a problem. What should I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The middleware you've shown runs some other code and *then* calls the wrapped Flask application.  However, `abort` raises exceptions that Flask handles, but aren't handled by WSGI directly.  Since you're not in the Flask application yet, it can't handle the exception.

A *much easier way* would be to do this check inside the Flask app.  Create a `before_request` handler that does basically the same thing as the middleware, except you can use `flask.request` rather than needing to parse the path and headers yourself.

```
from flask import request, abort

@app.before_request
def check_auth_token():
    if request.path in ('/authenticate', '/token'):
        return

    token = request.headers.get('X-ACCESS-TOKEN')

    if not verify_token(token):
        abort(401)

    check_permissions(get_token_payload(token))
```

---

If you *do* want to use WSGI middleware for this, you need to create the response yourself.  Conveniently, Werkzeug's exceptions behave like WSGI applications, so it's straightforward to use them.

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import Unauthorized

# in place of abort(401) in the middleware
return Unauthorized()(environ, start_response)
```

You can also use `abort` still by catching the exceptions it raises (which, again, are WSGI applications).

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort, HTTPException
# werkzeug.exceptions.abort is the same as flask.abort

try:
    abort(401)
except HTTPException as e:
    return e(environ, start_response)
```