# Flask middleware for specific route

Tags: python, flask, routes, middleware

I made API Server with Python Flask-RESTful.

My system use token authentication for verify permission.

So, I added middleware for verify token.

For example, code like this,

[middleware.py]

```py
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        print("gogo")
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

[app.py]

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from api.board import Article
from api.auth import Login, Register, RefreshToken
from middleware import Test


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Login, '/login')
api.add_resource(Register, '/register')
api.add_resource(RefreshToken, '/refresh')

# middleware here
app.wsgi_app = Test(app.wsgi_app)
api.add_resource(Article, '/article')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I insert `app.wsgi_app = Test(app.wsgi_app)` before `/article`.

So I expect that only access to `/article` will print *"gogo"*, however every route print *"gogo"*.

Maybe every route pass through with middleware.

How can I apply middleware for specific route? (In this code, only `/article`)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There are a few ways how to add custom processing before specific endpoint.

**1)** Using python decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def home_decorator():
    def _home_decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def __home_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            # just do here everything what you need
            print('before home')
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            print('home result: %s' % result)
            print('after home')
            return result
        return __home_decorator
    return _home_decorator


@app.route('/home')
@home_decorator()
def home():
    return 'Hello'
```

**2)** Using `before_request`

```
@app.before_request
def hook():
    # request - flask.request
    print('endpoint: %s, url: %s, path: %s' % (
        request.endpoint,
        request.url,
        request.path))
    # just do here everything what you need...
```

**3)** Using middleware. Just add condition on request path.

```
class Middleware:

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        # not Flask request - from werkzeug.wrappers import Request
        request = Request(environ)
        print('path: %s, url: %s' % (request.path, request.url))
        # just do here everything what you need
        return self.app(environ, start_response)


@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return 'Hello'


app.wsgi_app = Middleware(app.wsgi_app)
```

**4)** Also you can use `before_request_funcs` to set list of functions before specific blueprint.

```
api = Blueprint('my_blueprint', __name__)


def before_my_blueprint():
    print(111)


@api.route('/test')
def test():
    return 'hi'


app.before_request_funcs = {
    # blueprint name: [list_of_functions]
    'my_blueprint': [before_my_blueprint]
}

app.register_blueprint(api)
```

Comment: ... I was simply surprised at the popularity of the question. Just decided to add this: [after_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.after_request), [after_request_funcs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.after_request_funcs), [before_first_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request), [before_first_request_funcs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request_funcs)

Comment: [before_app_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.before_app_request), [preprocess_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.preprocess_request), [process_response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.process_response), [after_app_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Blueprint.after_app_request). Hope this helps

Comment: From my exp the best way to do something before a request in flask is to do it via @app.before_request hook. By this way you can take benefit of everything that flask provides out of box otherwise you can face problems like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264390/flask-middleware-on-abort-401-causing-a-500. Of Course typical flask middlewares have their own place in the world but for most general cases you will be best served by before_request.