# Reading token attached on headers in flask middleware gives "Working outside of request context" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jwt

I want to have middleware in my flask application to check for token, i do not want to use decorator, since there are hundreds of url routes.

middleware.py

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
import logging
import jwt
import traceback
from flask import request


class Middleware:
    """
    Middleware to check token
    """

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        try:
            token = request.headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]
            token_json = jwt.decode(token, "secret_key", algorithms=['HS256'], audience='account')
            environ['USER_DETAIL'] = token_json
            return self.app(environ, start_response)

        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(traceback.print_exc())
            res = Response(u'{}'.format(e), mimetype='text/plain', status=401)
            return res(environ, start_response)
```

this throws and error on line `token = request.headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flask_service/middleware.py", line 20, in __call__
    token = request.headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 348, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 307, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 37, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

I tried `environ["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]` it gives `key error` since HTTP_AUTHORIZATION key is not present.

How do i check for token passed in request header in middleware. Please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that `Middlewares` doesn't work with request context. You can combine not only `Flask` applications but any `WSGI` application. In this case you are running the same or different `Flask` applications that are entirely isolated from each other. They run different configurations and are dispatched on the `WSGI` level.
But you can create request instance manually:

```
from flask import Request

class Middleware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        # you can't use from flask import request, but you can create request instance using environ:
        request = Request(environ)
        print(request.headers)
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

JFYI: not sure if you need `middleware` here. You can use [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691730/flask-middleware-for-specific-route/51820573#51820573) to process authorization token.