# Is it possible to redirect inside a middleware class?

Tags: python, flask

```
class Middleware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app


    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        cookies = request.cookies
        path = request.path
        

        if not isAuthenticated(cookies):
            #Redirect to /login

        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

So I have a `Middleware` class that is supposed to get the `cookies` from the `request` and then send it to a function `isAuthenticated` which returns either `True` or `False` now if the function returns `False` I need to redirect to `/login` page is that possible to do? even though I don't have the `request` object I only have the `environ`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure. Because WSGI middleware is at a layer outside the app itself.

You can use [other hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691730/flask-middleware-for-specific-route/51820573#51820573) to work inside app / request context. In this case you can use `flask.request`, `flask.redirect()` etc. By the way, you don't need to initialize the request (`request = Request (Environment)`).

Comment: The issue is that I want this middleware to run on all routes without adding it manually to each route.

Comment: @KadiemAlqazzaz I understand. see `before_request_funcs` or `before_request` in the link 

Answer (score 2):

Its possible using HTTP 301 redirection:

```
class PrefixMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, app, prefix=''):
        self.app = app
        self.prefix = prefix

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        if environ['PATH_INFO'].startswith(self.prefix):
            environ['PATH_INFO'] = environ['PATH_INFO'][len(self.prefix):]
            environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = self.prefix
            return self.app(environ, start_response)
        else:
            start_response('301', [('Location', self.prefix)])
            return ["Redirecting to application...".encode()]
```