# Flask Middleware Class Raise Exception Not Catching

Tags: python, flask

Here is part of `app.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('SETTINGS')
app.wsgi_app = Middleware(app.wsgi_app, app)


@app.errorhandler(ValueError)
def all_exception_handler(error):
    print('Error Catched!')
    return 'Error Handler', 500
```

And here is part of `Middleware` class:

```
class Middleware:
    def __init__(self, wsgi, app):
        self.wsgi = wsgi
        self.app = app


    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):

        raise ValueError('Value Error')

        return self.wsgi(environ, start_response)
```

So my issue is when I raise `ValueError` exception inside `Middleware` (`raise ValueError('Value Error'`) the `@app.errorhandler(ValueError)` is not triggering thus I'm not receiving `print('Error Catched!')` in my console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello again my friend

I [told you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68458580/4929646) that `Middlewares` is out of app layer(outside of the request / outside of the Flask application etc) => application error handler will not work. Just move your logic into `@app.before_request` or `app.before_request_funcs`

Comment: Maybe you did not understand my previous answer (but I asked if it was clear). Just use `@app.before_request` +  `@app.errorhandler` + `flask.redirect()`

Comment: Yh I got it that's why I started the project again but with Django much more easier anyways thanks for you help

Comment: @KadiemAlqazzaz I understand ... `Django Middlewares` is a little different and understandable. Anyway feel free to ask a details in comments. good luck!